# How to upload application code to AWS Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a pre-built jar that I can deploy on an ec2-instance and it runs reading from a queue and processing some business logic. I want to use it with AWS Beanstalk but when I try to do that Beanstalk asks for application source code in a zip format. Does this mean that I have to provide the code of just my application? but there are a lot of jars that my application jar depends on and does this mean I must package the source code of those jars also with my application jar? Anyway I can just upload my application compiled jar

Answer (score 1):

There are two options for deployment to beanstalk.

1. you create a zip file of your application and upload it via the console
2. you use the **eb-cli** (from the command line) to create the zip file and do the deployment

Here is the documentation for java applications: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Java.html

And the documentation for the eb-cli:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3.html

After setting up the cli environment (getting ssh keys etc) you can deploy with `eb deploy`

Answer (score 0):

About uploading code to AWS Beanstalk it can be done through beanstalk console.
Having lot of jar file for application, you need to combine all the files in single source bundle and then need to upload.
Below link gives example of
[Bundling Multiple WAR Files for Tomcat Environments](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-tomcat-multiple-war-files.html)

Comment: So I guess I am confused about the term "source". Is it source code like a zip file with ".java" files or a bundled jar with ".class" files? I tried uploading a bundled jar with ".class" files and the environment immediately failed.